# C# Selenium Calendar click

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hope everyone is well. I am having difficulties with the clicking a calendar date.

Basically I click on a button a calendar pops up and when i inspect (google chrome) the date the following td is what I need to click;

```
<td class="dxeCalendarDay" savedcursor="[object Object]" style="cursor: pointer;">1</td>
```

I tried the following code but gave me an error;

```
FromCalendar = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpStart_DDD_C_mt"));
IWebElement FromCalendar1 = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '>1<'")); //

FromCalendar1.Click();
```

The error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //ttr/td[contains(text(), '>1<' because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//ttr/td[contains(text(), '>1<'' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how will i make it valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your XPath is that you are trying to locate the element by contained text of `>1<`. That element doesn't contain `>1<`, it only contains `1`. Change it to `//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='1']` and it should work.

Looking at your code, it looks like you have other issues.

Your first line doesn't do anything... I'm assuming you meant to click to open the calendar?

```
Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpStart_DDD_C_mt")).Click();
```

In general, if you aren't going to reuse the variable, don't bother storing a reference to the web element. Change

```
IWebElement FromCalendar1 = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '>1<'")); //
FromCalendar1.Click();
```

to just

```
Chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '>1<'")).Click();
```

Since you are clicking an element and a calendar opens, you should assume that it might not be instantly available so you should add a wait. Your final code would look something like this.

```
Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpStart_DDD_C_mt")).Click();
new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='1']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Thank You soo much. This solution worked. Fila code;  IWebElement FromCalendar = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpStart_B-1")); //
            FromCalendar.Click();

            new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='1']"))).Click();

Comment: Hi Maybe you can help me again. i have another issue not sure what im doing wrong but its the same principle; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900065/c-sharp-selenium-calendar-click-does-not-work-and-i-get-an-error

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close. This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //ttr/td[contains(text(), '>1<' because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//ttr/td[contains(text(), '>1<'' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that the **XPath** you have used wasn't a valid *XPath Expression*.

You have a couple of issues as follows:

- The `>` and `<` are the part of the tags so shouldn't be a part of the *XPath Expression*. So you need to remove them.
- You need to use either `contains()` or `text()` but not both.
- The *XPath Expression* needs to be in proper format.

So your own *XPath Expression* with minor modifications will be as follows:

```
IWebElement FromCalendar1 = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][text()='1']"));
//or
IWebElement FromCalendar1 = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[@class='dxeCalendarDay' and contains(.,'1')]"));
```

Further, as you will be clicking on a button element for calendar popup to appear, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//tr/td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][text()='1']"))).Click();
//or
new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//tr/td[@class='dxeCalendarDay' and contains(.,'1')]"))).Click();
```

Note: **ChromeDriver** is a reserved **keyword** which shouldn't be used as a *user defined variable* at any cost.

Comment: It doesn't "imply", it *states* that it isn't valid. Implies means it's not clearly stated but understood but the error message clearly states that it's not valid. You can use `contains()` and `text()` together... there are no issues with doing so. I'm not sure where you got that they can't both be used. So what does your answer provide that mine didn't? You didn't state anything (that was true) that my answer didn't already state.

Answer (score -1):

First I used this code

**var query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("..."))**; *// this will be looking for your (id/Css/Xpath..) and I created this 'var query to sent' the current DataTime*
**DateTime y = DateTime.Today;** *// this is my string (y) the current time*

**query.SendKeys(y.ToString());** *then I send my string (y) to my query (My problem here was the click, so I created this code to waiting my string (y) and Click*

**new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("rcToday"))).Click();**
*// Well when my string sent (y) my calendar would show me a DataTime but it weren't clickable, then I found the WebElement over the (y), in my case was (rcToday) and done I could click over it.*

```
var query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("..."));
DateTime y = DateTime.Today;
query.SendKeys(y.ToString());
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("rcToday"))).Click();
```

In other words, you can try it to pick up the day with this step bellow

```
            driver.FindElement(By.Id**("popupButton")).Click();// look your element

            river.FindElement(By.LinkText("13")).Click();// you could try by (Id/CssSelector/Xpath etc...) to click over the day, if the element is unclikable try to put the code bellow and look for the element the day  is selected and click.

            new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("rcWeekend"))).Click();// this class name were my element that i found.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation as well not just code.

Comment: @PeterCsala well I left my explanation, thanks for letting me know :) I hope it could help you