# C# Selenium Calendar click does not work and I get an error

Tags: c#, selenium, calendar

I was able to get helped by clicking on the first calendar and needed to do the same thing for the next calendar. SO i need to pick 1st day of the mon th on the first calendar nad for the 2nd calendar i need to click on the last day of next month. The schedule im creating is every two months.

THe first calendar pick is as follows and this works;

```
IWebElement FromCalendar = Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpStart_B-1")); //
        FromCalendar.Click();

        //Always Click the current 1st day of the month
        new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='1']"))).Click();
```

The second calendar is the following and does not work, i also created a variable that is included in the xpath but i get a timeout error and even if i change the seconds to 20 or 30 seconds i still get the same error. If i hard coded the value in the variable it still wouldnt work.

```
String LastDayofNextMonth = endOfLastDayNextMonth.ToString("dd");

        // 2nd Calendar
        Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpEnd_B-1Img")).Click(); ; //

        //Click next month because schedule should be every 2 months

        Chromedriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_dpEnd_DDD_C_NMCImg")).Click(); //


        //Always Click the last day of next month - so schedule is for every 2 months

        new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='"+LastDayofNextMonth+"']"))).Click();
```

The calendar does open and goes to the next month but the last day of the month is not clicked and i get the following error;

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 3 seconds'

I am not sure why the first calendar works and the second doesnt.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be a LOT easier if we could see the calendar. Don't suppose you can post a link to the page? You need to at least post the relevant HTML.

Comment: Im trying to get a screenshot. the website has a login and was able to logon automatically by using selenium. The website is done in ASPX and I cant see the calendar html coding behind it. On the website I ma trying to get the schedule from one calendar e.g. 1 Oct 2018 and second calendar to 30 Nov 2018 once the number 30 is automatically clicked the page refreshes and will be able to see the schedule between those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The Calendar had 2 day 30 therefore it was choosing the 30 of the month of October and should be the last day of next month which is Nov 30.

Final code;

```
new WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("(//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay'][.='"+LastDayofNextMonth+"'])[2]"))).Click();
```